# Access Denied error when restarting Publisher Service

Tags: 2011

I have had to reinstall Tridion 2011 from scratch. I followed the official instructions on how to configure users permissions but am getting an error in the when the publisher service starts.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Tridion Publishing" /> 
        <EventID Qualifiers="0">100</EventID> 
        <Level>2</Level> 
        <Task>0</Task> 
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-03-22T15:31:01.000000000Z" /> 
        <EventRecordID>63992</EventRecordID> 
        <Channel>Tridion</Channel> 
        <Computer>TCM01.MYDOMAIN.com</Computer> 
        <Security /> 
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>Access is denied for the user MYDOMAIN\tcmpublisher. Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing Errorcode: 0 User: MYDOMAIN\tcmpublisher StackTrace Information Details: at Tridion.ContentManager.Queuing.QueuingEngine.LoadAccessToken(String userName) at Tridion.ContentManager.Queuing.QueuingEngine..ctor() at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.QueueConsumerHandler.DoWork()</Data> 
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

I get nothing in the Tridion event log (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\log`) even with logback set to `DEBUG`. I can't think where else to look to find what's going wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: MYDOMAIN\tcmpublisher is added as a Administrator in SDL Tridion or configured as an Impersonation User?

Comment: Who is running the publisher service?

Comment: @BartKoopman `MYDOMAIN\tcmpublisher` is the user that the `Tridion Content Manage Publisher` service is running as. Ah, do I have to add them as a Tridion user?

Comment: @user978511 `MYDOMAIN\tcmpublisher` is the account running the publisher web service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user account running the Publisher service (in your case `MYDOMAIN\tcmpublisher`) should be an SDL Tridion Administrator account or configured as an Impersonation User in the SDL Tridion MMC snap-in.

This is because the Publisher has to run with Administrator privileges so all Template actions can be executed and all items can be read.

Comment: I added `MYDOMAIN\tcmpublisher` to the list of content manager users and made them administrator. All works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether MYDOMAIN\tcmpublisher is having Read/Write access to the installed Tridion Folder (generally c:\program files (x86)\tridion)

Additionally check, if the MTS User has been set up correctly in DCOM+ for SDL Tridion Content Manager (Ensure it is not locked and its password is working fine)

Comment: I set up the permissions as stated in the Tridion documentation. tcmpublisher shouldn't have read/write access to the tridion root, just read, or am I wrong? http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=CM_SecuritySettings_filesystem.xml&docid=concept_46DDF5D4AA10497AA1120A20B4A6307F&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_46DDF5D4AA10497AA1120A20B4A6307F

Comment: you are right; only read permission.